# Socket.IO / Express / Nuxt on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, socket.io, nuxt.js

I have written an Universal Nuxt chat application using socket.io. This is my first time digging into websockets and backend. I'm a beginner frontend developer. So on localhost everything works just perfect. But when I deploy my application on heroku it gives this error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?IO=3&transport=polling&t=MqxNTe3
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
index.js

const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const { app, server } = require('./app')

let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

async function start() {
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready()
  }

  app.use(nuxt.render)

  server.listen(port, () => {
    consola.ready({
      message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
      badge: true
    })
  })
}
start()




socket.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'

export default function({ store }) {
  Vue.use(
    new VueSocketIO({
      debug: false,
      connection: 'http://localhost:3000',
      vuex: {
        store,
        actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
        mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_'
      }
    })
  )
}






app.js

const app = require('express')()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const users = require('./users')()

const m = (name, text, id) => ({ name, text, id })

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('userJoined', (data, cb) => {
    if (!data.name || !data.room) {
      return cb('Данные некорректны')
    }

...
```

I see that in socket.js file I have connection property set to localhost
Maybe I should replace it with something that heroku expect from me?

Comment: UPD! I just added replaced the value of property connection: 'http://localhost:3000' with the web address of heroku app and it works but what if I will replace my app's name so the address will be replaced too. Do you guys know an solution?

Comment: You should use `env` variables in this case that could be read both on your local machine and on the Heroku environment (they are called `config vars` in this case)

Comment: do you have an reverse proxy?